# Why do I get an error when I use cascading ifs in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, operators

I have a program that takes one's income and multiplies it by a factor according to the income given. It also gives a code either 1 or 0 that defines the range of the incomes accordingly.
It seems correct on a first sight but I seem to get errors that concern the if statements that exist in the method that I use in order to calculate the incomes.

The code is the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class IncomeCalc{
    public void Cal(double inc, int code)
    {
        if( code == 0 )
        {
            if((inc >= 0) && (inc <= 5,000))
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.1);
            }else if((inc >= 5,001) && (inc <= 10,000))
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.15);
            }else if((inc >= 10,001) && (inc <= 20,000))
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.25);
            }else if(inc >= 20,001)
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.35);
            }               
        }
        else if( code == 1 )
        {
            if((inc >= 0) && (inc <= 10,000))
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.1);
            }else if((inc >= 10,001) && (inc <= 20,000))
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.15);
            }else if((inc >= 20,001) && (inc <= 30,000))
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.25);
            }else if(inc >= 30,001)
            {
                System.out.println("Your tax declaration is "+ inc*0.35);
            }               
        } 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your annual income");
        double income = obj.nextDouble();
        Scanner obj2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("If you are an individual choose 0 else choose 1 ");
        int decl = obj2.nextInt();

        Cal(income, decl);
    }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually using commas to separate digits? if so this is your issue, also don't create 2 scanner objects, use the same one for both operations.

Comment: Oh I see! How foolish of me. So if I want to represent the number two thousand it should be like: 2.000?

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't noticed it!

Comment: @user08 - If this answer helped you with your problem then **accept** it as **useful**.